# Programs built on Datasnap

Tags: delphi, n-tier-architecture, datasnap

I have done a search on Google for applications writen with Datasnap and didn't find much information.

1. What well know applications are written in Datasnap 2009 / 2010 ?
2. Is using Datasnap 2010 a viable choice compared to using other frameworks like RemObjects, Midware or kbmMW.

Cheers
AJ

Comment: Teasing: any application using TClientDataSet is technically using DataSnap as it is by default implemented in MIDAS.DLL ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think the applications written with datasnap will be mainly custom build applications and therefore not listed on any public website. At least all projects I have worked on that used datasnap were custom build applications.

Comment: I partially agree with you: communicating over DataSnap used to be pretty much an embarcadero-only technology (available both in Delphi and JBuilder). Now that DataSnap supports JSON it is much more open now (see http://wings-of-wind.com/2009/08/19/rad-studio-2010-review-11-datasnap/)

Comment: While that is true, the applications that you make with DataSnap (desktop client application communicating to a server [over an internet connection]) are not typically apps for the general public.